# Not able to get all information to display from local storage

Tags: javascript, html

This is supposed to be a reminder list with an input and output page. I currently have the information form the form saving in local storage but only displaying the most recent item added. How do I make it so everything from storage is displayed?
Ps I will make a button to delete the item later.

Input Page HTML

```
<form name="todoForm" action="" method="get">
    Reminder : <input type="text" name="ReminderInput" id="ReminderInput"><br />
    Date: <input type="datetime-local" name="DateInput" id="DateInput"><br />
    Extra Information : <input type="text" name="InfoInput" id="InfoInput"><br />
    <button onclick="storeValues(event)" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Input page JS

```
function storeValues(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let storedReminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Reminders")) || [];
const newReminderDetails = {
    ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
    DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
    InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value
}
storedReminders.push(newReminderDetails);
localStorage.setItem("Reminders", JSON.stringify(storedReminders));
console.log('storedReminders', storedReminders);    
}
document.getElementById("todoForm").addEventListener("submit",storeValues );
```

Output page HTML

```
<h1>Reminders
</h1>
<h4 id='ReminderInput'>&nbsp;</h4>
<h4 id='DateInput'>&nbsp;</h4>
<h4 id='InfoInput'>&nbsp;</h4>
```

Output page JS

```
const renderReminder = (reminder) => {
        document.getElementById('ReminderInput').textContent = reminder.ReminderInput;
        document.getElementById('DateInput').textContent = reminder.DateInput;
        document.getElementById('InfoInput').textContent = reminder.InfoInput;
    };
    renderReminder
    const storedReminders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Reminders"));
    if (!storedReminders) throw new Error('No Reminders');
    const lastReminder = storedReminders.pop();
    renderReminder(lastReminder);
```

Comment: You never loop over all the reminder iems in `storedReminders `  to render them....you only pop the last one off and  render it. Going to need to create new elements in the new loop to append to the page

Comment: I don't quite understand can you give an example?

Comment: You have an array of indeterminate length in `storedReminders `. If you want to render all those items you need to loop over the array and render elements for each item in the array. You have oversimplified it by having a single set of elements for only one item in the page

Comment: So you need to start doing some research into how to create and insert new elements and how to create an array loop to expose the individual items needed to create the elements from